# Fail to boot after installation onto ASUS PC 1015PX

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-netbook, boot-failure, asus

My new ASUS 1015PX has the usual Windows on the SDA1 partition - 100Gb, followed by SDA2 - 15Gb - as the recovery partition for Windows, and SDA3 with 183Gb for drive `D:\` for windows. ASUS uses SDA4 - 19Mb for it's own use.

11.10 on an USB will load Ubuntu on a try basis and it seems OK, but every time I attempt an install, Ubuntu quickly shuts down and the restart process begins. This repeats endlessly.

I've tried 10.04 Netbook Remix but that will not boot at all with the machine reporting - `unknown keyword in config file gfxboot vesamenu.c32: not a COM32R image`.

I've gone through the above about 6 times each with the same results.

I have also tried the above with the partitioning unchanged, and using gparted, with SDA3 formatted to ext4, windows `D:\` reduced to 8Gb providing a 175Gb unallocated space - all to no avail.

Further information: During my attempt to load 11.10, I notice that on the page which offers 3 options of loading, the first in the list includes the statement 'install INSIDE windows...' whereas the on line help shows 'install ALONGSIDE windows...'. (my caps for emphasis) I have double checked that I am using the correct download - not the install within windows option.

Comment: Wubi is a program that's laoded into the Ubuntu CDs so that you load the CD while in Windows and install Ubuntu within Windows. You can try this instead

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).